# Printer for paper visitors badge (event)

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, quickcontactbadge

I created an application where people can be checked in at an event. Now I am looking for a printer for these badges. I want it to be a6 or a7 format, and it has to be able to print in color. Now I have been doing some research on what printers to use, but most of them are labelprinters. I am not sure if these printers can be usefull for my use case.

Examples:
Zebra ZQ520
DYMO LabelWriter 4XL
Brother QL-820NWB

I would really apprecaite some help!

Thank you in advance